# Horror podcast by author

Tags: story-identification

I used to listen to a feed of a sci fi/horror author’s novels. He would read them himself. One was a trilogy about these alien beings who used some sort of spore to infect the human hosts. The mature alien looked sort of like a lily with eyes, if I remember correctly. He had another series about transhuman society where football was the focus, but having a rhino/human hybrid on your team, etc.
There was another series of some sort of resurrected killer mutant dog/lion/monster creatures were lab created and got loose.
Anyone recognize this author?

Comment: Yes! That’s it! Scott Siglar for sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [Scott Sigler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Sigler) and [his podcast](https://podcasts.google.com/?feed=aHR0cDovL2ZlZWRzLmZlZWRidXJuZXIuY29tL3Njb3R0c2lnbGVy). His alien infection story is the *[Infected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infected_(novel))* trilogy.

> The book follows several characters as they deal with an alien invasion on the microscopic level. The narration is primarily through the perspectives of Perry Dawsey, an ex-football player with an anger problem, and Margaret Montoya, an epidemiologist with the CDC who is investigating a strange disease that turns seemingly normal people into murderers.

The football series would be his *[Galactic Football League Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rookie_(novel))*.

> 'As a means to maintain order without violence, the Creterakians devised a distraction for the masses: the Galactic Football League. The GFL is a sports league modeled after the game of American football, with teams of varying skill separated into three tiers: the most skilled playing in Tier 1, the least skilled playing in Tier 3. The multi-species nature of society is reflected in the make-up of the GFL team lineups; the strengths of certain species make them natural fits for certain football positions. The quarterback, running back and tight-end positions are generally played by Humans. The female Sklorno, known for their speed and jumping ability, play the wide receiver and defensive back positions. The offensive and defensive lines are manned by Ki, a race of huge, agile creatures with enormous mass. And finally, the linebacker positions are played by Quyth Warriors and High-G Humans.
>
> *The Rookie* is the story of Quentin Barnes, a human Tier 3 quarterback raised in the Purist Nation. Quentin's planetary religion is that of the Purist Nation, which is very xenophobic. Even other evolutionary strains of human beings are clearly looked down upon - only "pure strain" humans are regarded as proper beings. As a result, Quentin has a very hard time trusting and working with his team-mates. The Purist Nation is composed entirely of humans. They shun and demonize any species other than humans, calling them the 'Satanic' or 'Lower' races. As a Tier 3 quarterback, Quentin is a superstar and a hero among the Purists, and he has used his talents to easily lead his third rate team to the championship of a Tier 3 division. His natural talent, coupled with his Purist Nation upbringing have made him extremely arrogant and racist.

Found with a search for `horror podcast author trilogy aliens football`